# Native Ad won't show on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, native-ads

My Native Ad can't seem to load and stay white like that :

[image]

In my XML i have two native ad:

```
<com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
                android:id="@+id/my_template"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view" />

<com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
                    android:id="@+id/my_template2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view" />
```

In my JAVA class, after initializing my Mobile.Ads:

```
AdLoader.Builder builder = new AdLoader.Builder(this, getString(R.string.nativead_ad_unit_id));
        builder.forUnifiedNativeAd(new UnifiedNativeAd.OnUnifiedNativeAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUnifiedNativeAdLoaded(UnifiedNativeAd unifiedNativeAd) {
                TemplateView template = findViewById(R.id.my_template);
                template.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);

                TemplateView template2 = findViewById(R.id.my_template2);
                template2.setNativeAd(unifiedNativeAd);


            }
        });

        AdLoader adLoader = builder.build();
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adLoader.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I also have the nativetemplates in my project

[image]

And in my dependencies

```
 implementation project(':nativetemplates')
```

LOG

```
I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out: [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
    [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out: [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out: [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
    [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzjk@76f792
        at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1759)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1787)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:751)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:55)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.ConnectionTracker.unbindService(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:50)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzis.zzah(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:242)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzis.zzak(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:259)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzis.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:321)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzir.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:7)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzgg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@@17.2.2:21)
```

All of my other Ads are working (Video Reward, Banner and Intertitiel). Any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: capture logs and update your question

Comment: Please check manifest. Internet permission must need to load ads. Also test ads with test ids provide by admob.

Comment: @DaxeshVekariya Hi! I already have it, as I said all of my other ads are working. It's just the native Ad that don't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes some time its happen. But no need to worry. You can upload the app on store and check again with live ads unit.

Comment: @DaxeshVekariya Hi again! I did what you said an uploaded it with the live ad unit but the problem is the same, the ads still look like in my post. Maybe I did not initialized it correctly but I can't find where. Do you have another idea?

Comment: Please share full activity code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Try with `layout_height="match_parent"` or specify a width